# Global static var provided by third party not concurrency safe

Tags: swift, async-await, concurrency

I have the following code declared at the top of my AppDelegate file, in the global scope.

```
let commandLineArguments = CommandLine.arguments
```

Xcode displays the warning `Reference to static property 'arguments' is not concurrency-safe because it involves shared mutable state`. How can I address this warning?

Comment: This isn't a general solution for this kind of problem, but I usually use `ProcessInfo.processInfo.arguments`, which is not mutable, instead of `CommandLine.arguments`.

Comment: Ye, the third party is the swift standard library @Rob so I can't change its implementation. It seems it doesn't matter where I put it, the warning in Xcode 14 is still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a library or even one type from it that you want to use doesn’t support strict concurrency checking yet, you can add `@preconcurrency` before `import` to tell the compiler that you are importing a library that hasn’t been updated for Sendable checking yet:

```swift
@preconcurrency import Foundation
```

Or, specifically import the enum itself:

```swift
@preconcurrency import enum Foundation.CommandLine
```

When the type or the library gets updated for the Sendable checking, the compiler will tell you that `@preconcurrency` before your import is not needed anymore, and you can safely delete it.